# How to Capture just the value from a PostgreSQL Query

Tags: python, postgresql, airflow

I am trying to capture the only the record from a PostgreSQL statement. The select statements outputs one row with column named as updated_at and the value is a timestamp- '2008-01-01 00:50:01'. I want to just capture/collect that value so when I call that variable, it just outputs '2008-01-01 00:50:01'.

Here is my code:

```
def get_etl_record():
    pg_hook = PostgresHook(postgre_conn_id="post", schema='schema1')
    connection = pg_hook.get_conn()
    cursor = connection.cursor()
    cursor2 = connection.cursor()
    latest_update_query = "select max(updated_at) from my_table group by updated_at"
    cursor.execute(latest_update_query)
    #results= cursor.fetchall()
    columns = [col[0] for col in cursor.description]
    rows = [dict(zip(columns, row[0])) for row in cursor.fetchall()]
    print(rows)
```

However this code doesnt give me an output.

Any ideas or suggestions?

Comment: What have you done to debug this? Have you tried printing the values at different steps of the way? Checking if the contents of the DB actually change?

Comment: The code creates a dictionary from the returned columns and rows. If only values are required to be captured, why not exclude columns?

Comment: Are you using MySQL or Postgres?

Comment: i am using MySQL

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to do what you want, but 3 ways to do very similar:

1.

```
cursor = connection.cursor()
cursor.execute(sql)
result = cursor.fetchone()
max_updated_at = result[0]
```

2.

```
dict_cur = connection.cursor(cursor_factory=psycopg2.extras.DictCursor)
dict_cur.execute('select max(updated_at) as max_updated_at ...')
result = dict_cur.fetchone()
max_updated_at = result['max_updated_at']
```

3.

```
nt_cur = connection.cursor(cursor_factory=psycopg2.extras.NamedTupleCursor)
nt_cur.execute('select max(updated_at) as max_updated_at ...')
result = nt_cur.fetchone()
max_updated_at = result.max_updated_at
```

Comment: It is now giving me the error of TypeError: tuple indices must be integers, not str. Do you know why that is?

Comment: `print(result)`